# Cells all becomes NaN after reordering alphabetically

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

After I tried to sort my Pandas dataframe by the `country` column with:

```
times_data2.reindex_axis(sorted(times_data2['country']), axis=1)
```

My dataframe became something like:

```
Argetina    Argentina   ....  United States of America ...

NaN         Nan         ....  NaN   ....
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the index of the dataframe to sorted countries:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['Brazil', 'USA', 'Argentina'], 'val': [1, 2, 3]})

>>> df
     country  val
0     Brazil    1
1        USA    2
2  Argentina    3

>>> df.set_index('country').sort_index()
           val
country       
Argentina    3
Brazil       1
USA          2
```

You may want to transpose these results:

```
>>> df.set_index('country').sort_index().T
country  Argentina  Brazil  USA
val              3       1    2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort by a column, use [`.sort_values()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
times_data2.sort_values(by='country')
```

Then use `.set_index('country')` if necessary.